# Create a Multiplication Table program, by using the Java user defined Method & For loop, the output will be according to the parameter passed

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, parameter-passing, multiplication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7WZR.png)
i am asked to make exactly this table but i am unable to figure out how the defined methods work!?

i have tried a lot but it just fails
don,t what i am doing wrong!

```
public class TABLE {
    public int Multiplication; 
    public int multiply(int num)
    {
            
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
        System.out.printf("%d * %d = %d \n", num, i, num * i);
        }
    return multiply;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your failure message?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I believe that your method doesn’t need to return anything. So declare it `public void multiply(int num)` and delete the line `return multiply;`. That should be it. Call the method like `new TABLE().multiply(10);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void multiply(int num)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
        System.out.printf("%d * %d = %d \n", num, i, num * i);
    }
}
```

hi，bro, you can

Answer (score 0):

```
//using user defined method By ITinnovation
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Table1
{
    public void tab(int num1)
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
        {
            //System.out.println("The Table is:"+num1*i);
            int multi=num1*i;
            System.out.println(num1 + " x " + i + " = " + multi);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
            System.out.printf("Enter that value which you want to find out the table:");
            Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
            int num1= sc.nextInt();
            Table1 obj= new Table1();
            obj.tab(num1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).